# Changing the background color in JasperReports based on field value

Tags: java, jasper-reports

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change text field data color (Foreground color) based on condition in JasperReports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754448/change-text-field-data-color-foreground-color-based-on-condition-in-jasperrepo)

Can I change the background color of an element in *JasperReports* depending on the color value I have stored in a field?

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9521341/1437586 and this docs http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/sample.reference/jasper/index.html#conditionalstyles

Comment: Not exactly the same since I'm not able to do the same with backcolor property as I do with forecolor property.

Comment: thanks, but what I need is that the color of the row is the one that is stored in a field.
sorry for my English