# Using color codes in list component in ireport designer

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I want to display a list of items ordered by their sales amount. I want to use some color code for displaying high, medium and low with actual values. i.e. each item in list will contain the no, item name, color code(in a square) and sales amount. Is this possible in iReport designer? Also I want to apply a vertical scroll bar to my list. How both this can be achieved in iReport designer.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

what I understand from above your question, I think you need to display different color based on high, medium, etc. with sales amount.

By applying **Conditional Styles**, you can able to get your requirement

[Formatting field data color based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536176/jasper-reports-formatting-field-data-color-based-on-condition)

For example, if salesamount is between X and Y, you can apply a specific style using the color you want.

[conditional style reference](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/how-apply-conditional-formatting-your-text-fields)

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Can we add conditional styles to images? For example I need one image for High values, another image for medium and another one for low values?