# Dashboard Visualization

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to build a report that displays Consumption for food items.
I have range like:

above 75% - High

50-75% - medium

below 50% - low

and want to associate a color code with that range:

High : Green

Medium : Blue

Low : Red

Now I want to build a report that will display top five consumed products.
a triangular flag must be displayed in the color for that range with the actual percentage value displayed inside the flag. The list of products will be created dynamically so it may contain 5 products with consumption in any combination. e.g at a particular time it may display 1 high and 4 medium consumed products or all high or low or medium consumed products.
 Thus the flag must be changed according to the consumption type having the consumption value displayed inside it.
Is it possible in *iReport* designer to design such a report? How it can be done?

Comment: 1) You should post the screenshot 2) What have you already tried?

Comment: I tried to post a screenshot but it requires 10 reputation... :(

Comment: And I don't know how to draw and fill a triangle in iReport Designer

Comment: You can post the link as comment - I'll put it in your question

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using color codes in list component in ireport designer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25010627/using-color-codes-in-list-component-in-ireport-designer)

Comment: Yes Alex, It is a duplicate of the same and that post was also from me. But I wanted to draw a triangle. After searching for the solution I found that triangle can't be drawn in ireport so I used text fields for color codes. Thanks for your support and interest. Still if you can tell me if it is possible to draw rectangles in iReport. Thanks